# laravel 5 subdomain not working in live

Tags: php, laravel-5, subdomain

I have a site that can be access in `stage.mysite.com` now I want to have a subdomain for another page and it can be access at `profile.stage.mysite.com`.

in my server I have configured the hosting.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName stage.mysite.com
ServerAlias *.stage.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.mysite.com/public
```

in my routes.php this is the code.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'profile.stage.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@profile');
});
```

but when I tried to access `http://profile.stage.mysite.com` returns `Server not found` error. any ideas how to access my static page into subdomain?

Comment: I think the issue with your hosting configuration.

Comment: thanks Vicky for the reply, can you show me which part?

Comment: Are you able to ping `profile.stage.mysite.com`?

Comment: I agree with @MarcoAurélioDeleu you need to check to make sure that subdomain is resolving to the correct IP address.

Comment: no reply when I try to ping.

Comment: So it's not a Laravel nor PHP problem. You first need to setup your sub-domain at your server's configuration and make sure the DNS Zone replies to that.

Comment: thanks mate I have fixed the issue