# laravel 5 subdomain redirected to homepage

Tags: php, laravel-5, subdomain

I have a site that can be access in `stage.mysite.com` and it has a subdomain `profile.stage.mysite.com` but it displays the content of `stage.mysite.com` when I try to access it.

in my server I have configured the hosting.

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName stage.mysite.com
ServerAlias *.stage.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/staging.mysite.com/public
```

in my routes.php this is the code.

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'profile.stage.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@profile');
});
```

this I expect to be called. any ideas?

This is my entire routes.php

```
Route::get('testemail', function() {
    return view('emails.new-group');
});
Route::get('decode', function(){
    var_dump(json_decode('[{"key":"wifi","info":"dasdasd"}]'));
});
require 'routes_backend.php';

Route::controller('/app', 'UserController');

// homepage
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('homepage');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'test'], function() {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function($company){
        Route::get('tester', function($company){
            return $company;
        });
    });
});
// subdomain 
Route::group(['domain' => 'profile.stage.mysite.com'], function()
{
    Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@dummyresort');
});
```

Comment: Can you post your full `routes.php` file?

Comment: I have posted my code from my routes.php

Comment: Try to move the `Route::group` directive that has the sub-domain up so it comes before the `Route::get('/')`.

Comment: thanks marco.. it helps me alot :) I move the code in the top and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future references, here is the answer and the concept:

Before trying to analyze the problem at the application level, [make sure that you can ping your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100821/laravel-5-subdomain-not-working-in-live) using the subdomain.

After that is settled, the catch here is the same principle as firewalls and NAT: **The more restrictive comes first**. In this case, the subdomain would show the same information as the main domain because in the **routes.php** file the  homepage `/` is declared first.

```
 // homepage 
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('homepage'); 
 });
```

When you navigate to the sub-domain, he matches this route and then it gets served and the request is finished. Since this is a much broader (without any limitation whatsoever) route, it should be the last thing to be declared, so when a subdomain route comes in, it finds first it's own restricted routes and matches to serve.